# ReactiveMongo: find() does not return anything when seeking by a field different that _id

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

Here below are four statements that should return the same document, i.e. the one with id `52dfc13ec20900c2093155cf` and email `me@gmail.com`:

```
val collection = ReactiveMongoPlugin.db.collection[JSONCollection]("users")

collection.indexesManager.ensure(
  Index(List("email" -> IndexType.Ascending), unique = true)
) 

// Returns one document, i.e. the one identified by 52dfc13ec20900c2093155cf
collection.find(Json.obj("_id" -> Json.obj("$oid" -> "52dfc13ec20900c2093155cf"))).cursor[JsValue].headOption

// Returns a list containing one element, i.e. the one identified by 52dfc13ec20900c2093155cf
val query = collection.find(son.obj("_id" -> Json.obj("$oid" -> "52dfc13ec20900c2093155cf"))).options(QueryOpts(skipN = 1)).cursor[JsValue].collect[Vector](1)

// Returns the same document as above, but found by email instead of by id
collection.find(Json.obj("email" -> "me@gmail.com")).cursor[JsValue].headOption

// Returns an empty list (it should return the same document as above)
val query = collection.find(Json.obj("email" -> "me@gmail.com")).options(QueryOpts(skipN = 1)).cursor[JsValue].collect[Vector](1)
```

The first two calls to `find` work as expected, i.e. they return the document identified by the given id. The third call to `find` also works and returns the same document as the previous calls. The problem is the last call... I'd expect it returns a list containing one document, but it doesn't. It just returns an empty list. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking one record to be skipped as part of your query.

QueryOpts(skipN = 1))

I assume you did not intend to do this?

Comment: Yes... the original code is >>>  collection.find(selector).options(QueryOpts(skipN = page * perPage)).cursor[JsValue].collect[Vector](1)<<<, where 'page' is the page number and 'perPage' is the number of document per page... It zero-based, so the first 'page' should be 0, not 1. Now it works. Thank you very much :-)